# using \r in {sub} of substitute() function call

Tags: vimscript, substitute

I want to write a zsh vi-mode helper to wrangle complex commands but ran into a snag using `\r` in a `substitute()` function invocation. It results in `\r` replaced with control characters `^M` in output. This works for command mode invocations, both mapping and creating a custom user command.

I've tried using single/double quotes for the {sub} string and surrounding the function declaration with `set cpo+=C` and `set cpo-=C` and replacing
`\r` with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (to get `^M`) but no joy.

The snippet below works for `<leader>s`, `:Split` but not for `:Test`

```
" .../after/ftplugin/zsh.vim
"
setlocal ts=2 sw=2 et sts=2 ai si

" For zsh vi-mode command split
" splits a single line command on every -- or -,
" appends \ on every eol
" mnemonic: cs = command split

" mapping shortcut to command works
" 1: Create a map, ask for confirmation
nmap <leader>s  :s:\(\s\{1,}\)\(-\+\): \\\r  \2:g<CR>  | noh | retab
nmap <leader>sq :s:\(\s\{1,}\)\(-\+\): \\\r  \2:cg<CR> | noh | retab

" user command works 
" 2: Create a User Command
command! -nargs=0 Split  s:\(\s\{1,}\)\(-\+\): \\\r\t\t\2:g  | noh | retab
command! -nargs=0 Splitq s:\(\s\{1,}\)\(-\+\): \\\r\t\t\2:cg | noh | retab

" 3: VimScript function doesn't work
" Fails with: ls -l -a
" EXPECT:
" ls\
"   -l\
"   -a
"
" GOT    : ls\^M -l\^M -a

command! -nargs=0 Test call SplitCommandLine()

func! SplitCommandLine()
  let pat    = '\(\s\{1,}\)\(-\+\)'
  let sub    = '\\\r \2'
  let flags  = 'g'
  let line   = getline('.')
  call setline('.', substitute(line, pat, sub, flags))
endf
```

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim @amal and thanks for the interesting and very well formulated question!

Comment: Thanks @filbranden! happy to be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not really with `substitute()`, but with [`setline()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setline%28%29), which will not break lines on `^M` and won't really offer a direct way to insert new lines at the place where the current line is being replaced.

You can pass `setline()` a list (which you can easily get by `split()`ing on `"\r"`), but that will actually *replace* the following lines, rather than inserting new lines for the continuation.

So, in order to make this work, you need to use `setline()` for the current line, followed by [`append()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#append%28%29) for the following lines.

The code below will do so:

```
func! SplitCommandLine()
  let pat    = '\(\s\{1,}\)\(-\+\)'
  let sub    = '\\\r \2'
  let flags  = 'g'
  let line   = getline('.')
  let repl   = split(substitute(line, pat, sub, flags), "\r")
  call setline('.', repl[0])
  call append('.', repl[1:])
endfunction
```

But arguably the best solution here is to stick to the `:s` Ex command (which you can easily call from a function), which already does what you need, without you having to jump through hoops to make it do it...

Comment: Oh neat! Interesting `setline` IO nursing effects the flow which highlights how flexible `:s` is for this task. Thanks @filbranden